# Permission Set Groups feature is not available in the Salesforce production org

Tags: production, permission-set-groups

I have Permission Set Groups created in my scratch org, but when I am trying to deploy it to the production org it is showing an error "Not available for deploy for this organization".

When I check the production org I found that the Permission Set Groups feature is not available in the production org.

[image: Screenshot of production org]

Can anyone help on Why this feature is not available in my Salesforce Production org? and How to enable this feature in the Production org?

Comment: feature is only available in these editions: `Available in: Professional, Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer Editions` what edition is your PROD org?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, actually we are using it in the Enterprise Edition, used by my company only. I have logged the case in the partner community and got one reply from them. Though the answer is not resolving our issue at least I got the reason for this. But anyhow thanks for your valuable time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [docx](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.perm_set_groups_create.htm&type=5), Permission set group is available for the users whom having the system permission `Manage Profiles and Permission Sets` in his profile.

So can you please check whether you're current profile having this permission?

If yes, Please `log a case` to Salesforce because this feature is already released on `Spring'20` Release.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for replying, actually I am having the Administrator profile and Manage Profiles and Permission Sets is enabled for the profile. I think I have to log a case to salesforce then. Thank you so much for your quick response.

Answer (score 3):

I have logged the case as you have suggested. The case was handled by the support team and finally got the following reply from the Manager of the Support team.

"We have contacted the concerned team, that deals with the activation of these perms. After a thorough evaluation, they have confirmed that there is no other workaround available to enable these perms. These have been locked from within the system and cannot be enabled. This is because the perm in question was not available in the Org's that were created prior to Spring '20. The only workaround available to get over this would be to create another Developer Org. This is a system limitation with a very limited scope of influence for change or edit. "

Though the problem is not solved, I really appreciate your time and effort in guiding me on the right path.

Thanks once again.